# Replace the CSS (Or Page Elements) in a page with a button (Drupal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find out if there is a possible way to replace the css in a page in drupal, using JavaScript/Jquery in the form of a button.

So for example, when the page loads, it will have a white background, with black buttons and black text, but on the page would be a button, that when pressed, will change the page to a black background, with white buttons and white text, sort of 'inverse' i guess you could say.

i was thinking if it was possible to use either JavaScript or jQuery to do this.

So essentially, it would change the look of a page (mostly colors of boxes and text) with the press of a button.

Comment: toggle a class on body and have css rules set up for different theme when that class is applied

Comment: use jquery/javascript to add/remove class(es) when you press the button

Answer (score 0):

This does not have anything to do with drupal.

You can add a class to the `<body>` tag, on your button click. And then style nested html elements based on this style.

```
 // using javascript
 document.body.className += " newClassName";
 // using jQuery
 $("body").addClass("newClassName");
```